# BrowserCookieError: Can not find cookie file

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, cookies

I was using browsercookie library and it was awesome. However, at some moment it just stopped working and I cannot see why.

Basically, it throws the error that it cannot locate cookie file at /Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies

Google and Stackoverflow search does not give a hint where to look for an error. Would appreciate any help.

Mac OS 10.11.3, Chrome Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit), python2.7, pysqlite preinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution turned to be tricky: when you add or change profiles, sometimes Chrome changes folders where it stores cookies. In my case the solution was to change "Default" word in cookie path to "Profile 2".